# Инкремент в javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
'use strict';
var years = prompt('Сколько вам лет?', 100);
years = years++;
alert('Вам ' + years + ' лет!');
```

Почему после выражения `years = years++;` переменная years не увеличивается на единицу, а остается равной 100?

Я понимаю, что выражение не корректное, но меня интересует механизм языка в данном случае. По идее, переменной years должно было сначала присвоиться ее же старое значение, то есть 100, а затем эта же переменная должна была увеличиться на 1 инкрементом. Но alert выводит все равно 100. Почему так?

Comment: Я это понимаю ,в моем коде ошибка, но мне интересно почему язык работает именно так, а не иначе.

Comment: `years = ++years;` – сначало увеличивает, потом возвращает. `years = years++;` – увеличивает, но возвращает старое значение

Comment: Да, так я пробовал и оно работает, но интересует постфиксный инкремент.

Comment: @Александр, кстати, выражение `years =  years++;` - вполне корректное, хотя и лишено смысла.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`years = years++` эквивалентно:

```
tmp = years;
years++;
years = tmp;
```

В отличие от `years = ++years;`, как справедливо отметил @Doofy. Постфиксный инкремент возвращает значение переменной ДО увеличения на 1, префиксный - значение после.

Насколько я знаю, инкремент работает именно так во всех ЯП, в которых он есть. Поэтому, кстати, в циклах предпочтительно использовать префиксный инкремент при прочих равных - меньше накладных расходов.

Например `i++` выведет 0-1-2-3-4, а не 1-2-3-4-5

```js
for (i=0; i<5;) console.log(i++);
```

```js
for (i=0; i<5;) console.log(++i);
```

Comment: вот теперь все начинает проясняться, но не совсем понятно почему мой код `years = years++` эквивалентен `tmp = years;
years++;
years = tmp;`

Comment: @Александр потому, что именно так устроен постфиксный оператор инкремента. Практически - по определению оператора `++`. Думаю, что так устроено для того, чтобы `i=0; a[i++] = some_value;` присваивало `some_value` 0-му элементу массива, а *потом* увеличивало индекс.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответы, теперь все понятно.